# Explode a string into into 3 or 4-word strings

Tags: php, arrays, string, split, explode

```
$str =  "Hello fri3nd, you're looking good today!  What a Great day this is!  How     fancy and cool!";
$pieces = explode(" ",$str, 3);

print_r($pieces);
```

This gives me:

```
$pieces[0] = 'Hello';
$pieces[1] = 'fri3nd,';
$pieces[2] = 'you\'re looking good today!  What a Great day this is!  How     fancy and cool!';
```

How can I explode into every 3 or 4 words?

Comment: In your title, you are asking about equal portions, in the question, you ask about every 3 or 4 words. Which one is it and how do you want it to work exactly?

Comment: Can u explain a bit more about your requirement and situation? Why do u want to split by 3 or 4 words? if u can explain your requirement, we may point a best solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857441/php-explode-over-every-other-word-with-a-twist and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840807/wondering-how-to-do-php-explode-over-every-other-word

Comment: You can also try [`preg_match_all('~(?:\S+\s*){1,3}(?<!\s)~', $str, $out)`](https://tio.run/##FY49C8IwGIT3/IorCEm0g@LmBx3tWHBwsFJCP4Mxb0lSpIj@9dre8Bw8t1zf9dN0SrI0Y2zlg8MZPK2NITRO720VY6Qh566GIXpq26IlqhCoUmME3DoVoHBx9dyzQui0h/bzlNIbSxplyxHKViiJTMSPjOlG9K5ui5cKZVcoYwT/ieSQXze5X8vPLt5/RXKKci9/PMZyayYNQUp8GNA7bUPhxKLu24c8su80/QE) though the idea from @mickmackusa is very nice and possible more efficient!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:?

```
<?php
$str =  "Hello fri3nd, you're looking good today!  What a Great day this is!  How     fancy and cool!";

$array = array_map(create_function('$a', 'return implode(" ", $a);'), array_chunk(preg_split('/\s+/', $str), 3));
var_dump($array);
```

Explanation:

- first you split the string at any (combined) whitespace: [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)
- then 'split' the resulting array: [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)
- you then apply [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) on any resulting group of words

Comment: Why use regular expression where you could use `explode(' ',` as well? `Explode` is faster.

Comment: @Matthieu because you'll possibly get empty array entries (see the many spaces near the end of the string)

Answer (score 1):

Make 3 or 4 repetitions of a regex pattern that matches one or more visible characters followed by one or more whitespace characters.

This will produce strings of three/four words, with the exception of the last element which may have less than three/four words depending on the total word count.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/08lM9))

```
$str = "Hello fri3nd, you're looking good today!  What a Great day this is!  How     fancy and cool!";

var_export(
    preg_split('/(?:\S+\K +){3}/', $str)
);
```

This is an adjustment of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76192679/2943403) which doesn't need to accommodate multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use the php [`str_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function:-

```
$pieces = str_split( $str, 3);
```

Comment: that doesnt split according to words.  it just smashes the whole thing into pieces.  explode splits by words, but I'm not able to choose the way it's "exploding" them apart.