# php split a string[] into 3 parts

Tags: php, arrays, string

I would like to split an array of strings into 3 parts (in PHP), however I do not know if the number of words will be divible by 3. 
   what would you do in this instance?

let's say i had a larger amount of text than this example
example input:    'Here is a sentence of random lenth'

example output:  'Here is', 'a sentence', 'of random length'

Comment: possible duplicate of [php : exploding string into equal portions. How do i do it!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173250/php-exploding-string-into-equal-portions-how-do-i-do-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with the Modulus operand (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

```
$words = explode(' ',$string);
$numberOfWOrds = count($words);
if($numberOfWords % 3 == 0){
    //dividable by three
}else {
    // not dividable by three
}
```

Comment: i guess I can pop the last element until it is divisible by 3

Comment: If you don't care about the last elements, you can just `floor($numberOfWords)/3` to get the number of words per output. Then simply iterate by this number over your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"apple","b"=>"grapes","c"=>"Horse","d"=>"Cow");
print_r(array_chunk($a,2,true));
?>
```

output will be

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [a] => apple [b] => grapes)
[1] => Array ( [c] => Horse [d] => Cow )
)
```

I think you can use `array_chunk()`.