# Generate an array of two-word strings which do not include blacklisted words

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, cpu-word, blacklist

I have an array with single words in them, for example:

```
[
    'This'
    'is',
    'a',
    'test',
    'array',
]
```

Next, I create another array with overlapping 2-word pairs which looks like this:

```
[
    'This is',
    'is a',
    'a test',
    'test array',
]
```

I have an array of "common words"; those words should be used to exclude pairs of words from the result array.

Let's say those common words would be `is` and `a` for this example. Right now, I search for common words first on the single word array so I can use `if(in_array($word, $common_words)) continue;` which makes it skip the one if it's in the common_words array.

But this would result in this array:

```
[
    'This test',
    'test array',
]
```

But this is not how I want it to happen. It should be like this:

```
[
    'test array',
]
```

Because this is the only 1 that had these 2 words next to each other originally before we started to take out the 'common_words'. (are you still with me?)

The problem here is that `if(in_array)` doesn't work anymore if I have an array with 2 words. So I did some research and stumbled upon the `array_filter` command. I think this is what I need but I'm at a total loss as on how to use/apply it to my code.

Comment: could you give me a piece of code that you had tried

Comment: @RagavendranRamesh I haven't used the `array_filter` yet since i don't really know how to use it. But as i wrote above i used to solve this issue with taking out the common words before i made a 2-word-array.

Comment: use array_unique() 'Removes Duplicate values from an Array' http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Related to the input generation: [Get each word with its next word from a space-delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74160879/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is correct, you can use:

```
$array = ['this is', 'array array', 'an array', 'test array'];
$stop  = ['is', 'test'];

$array = array_filter($array, function($x) use ($stop)
{
   return !preg_match('/('.join(')|(', $stop).')/', $x);
});
```

-i.e. exclude all items with certain words in it by pattern using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter)

This will work with filtering because it will match *by regex*, i.e. from `$stop` we'll get regex `(is)|(test)`

A good idea will be to evaluate regex separately so do not evaluate it each time inside `array_filter()` iteration, like:

```
$array   = ['this is', 'array array', 'an array', 'test array'];
$stop    = ['is', 'test'];
$pattern = '/('.join(')|(', $stop).')/';

$array = array_filter($array, function($x) use ($pattern)
{
   return !preg_match($pattern, $x);
});
```

*Important note#1*: if your stop words may contain some special characters that will be treated in regex in special way, it's needed to use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) like:

```
$pattern = '/'.join('|', array_map(function($x)
{
   return '('.preg_quote($x, '/').')';
}, $stop)).'/';

$array = array_filter($array, function($x) use ($pattern)
{
   return !preg_match($pattern, $x);
});
```

*Important note#2*: If your array of stopwords is too long this may cause regex compilation fail because of it's length (too large). There are some tricks to overcome it, but if it's your case, you'd better to use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) instead:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($x) use ($stop)
{
   foreach($stop as $word)
   {
      if(false!==strpos($x, $word))
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it! Can you maybe explain what exactly the `.join` does in the preg match?

Comment: Nice. But `strpos`/`stripos` would be faster than `preg_match`

Comment: It gives me `unkown modifier 'o'` for some reason if i use it in another code.

Comment: It happens when I replace the `$stop` with my own array which is called `$common_words`

Comment: A list of words, let me paste a little example, hold on.

Comment: `'diens', 'dezer', 'dezes', 'nr', 'no', 'wij', 'ik', 'jij',` i copied this from the middle of the array. This shouldn't be weird right

Comment: Yeah, it works fine as well too when I use it in another file. [Here is the array I was talking about by the way](http://pastebin.com/dbYVw5P3) It's 2050 lines long so be prepared.

Comment: Hey, thanks this worked! Do you think you could explain to me why it didn't work? and why it needed the `preg_quote` instead?

Comment: Ok thanks. Jeez, i feel so helpless. It says `Compilation failed: regular expression is too large` does this mean my array is too big?

Comment: Sorry to be such a pain. But it says `strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter` i looked it up and that means there must be a empty value somewhere inside `$common_words`.

Comment: Oh wait i think i fixed it using `$common_words = preg_grep('/^\s*\z/', $common_words, PREG_GREP_INVERT);`

Comment: Well enough spam already from my side. I can't thank you enough for helping me through this maze. It works now thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the bes way, two operators: array_diff and array_unique

```
$a[] = 'This';
$a[] = 'is';
$a[] = 'is';
$a[] = 'a';
$a[] = 'a';
$a[] = 'test';
$a[] = 'test';
$a[] = 'array';

$excluded = array('is', 'a');

$result = array_diff($a, $excluded); // Remove all excluded words
$result = array_unique($result); // unique values

var_dump($result);
```

And result:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'This' (length=4)
  5 => string 'test' (length=4)
  7 => string 'array' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will require a loop to generate your array of word-pairs, so during that same process, implement the filtering logic.

Check for any intersecting values using the values in each pair against the blacklist array. In there are no matching values, push the couple of words into the result array as a space-delimited string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GXZ3e))

```
$string = "This is a test array";
$blacklist = ['is', 'a'];
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$result = [];
for ($i = 1, $max = count($words); $i < $max; ++$i) {
    $couple = [
        $words[$i - 1],
        $words[$i]
    ];
    if (!array_intersect($blacklist, $couple)) {
        $result[] = implode(' ', $couple);
    }
}
var_export($result);
```