# PHP explode on second instance of a delimiter

Tags: php, explode

I am trying to explode a string using PHP but when only if the second instance of the delimiter is detected before exploding it, for my case i want to explode it after the second space is detected.

My String

`Apple Green Yellow Four Seven Gray`

My desire output

```
Apple Green
Yellow Four
Seven Gray
```

My initial code

```
$string = 'Apple Green Yellow Four Seven Gray';
$new = explode(' ',$string);
```

How can i achieve this using explode or any separating method with PHP? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice question - it can be done in many way. i came up with this 1 -

```
 $data='Apple Green Yellow Blue';


$split = array_map(
    function($value) {
        return implode(' ', $value);
    },
    array_chunk(explode(' ', $data), 2)
);

var_dump($split);
```

Comment: In my case it only returned `Array ( [0] => Apple Green [1] => Yellow Four Seven Gray ) ` somehow it missed the `Seven Gray`

Comment: okay @KaoriYui ..i did it wrong please see my updated answer ..it will work perfect

Comment: Ok so Ive changed the delimiter to space and change the var_dump into print_r, this is the simplest, thanks!

Comment: oh again ...sorry mate ..i updated it to space delimiter .

Answer (score 2):

You can use this also :

```
$string = 'Apple Green Yellow Four Seven Gray';
$lastPos = 0;
$flag = 0;
while (($lastPos = strpos($string, " ", $lastPos))!== false) {  
    if(($flag%2) == 1)
    {
        $string[$lastPos] = "@";
    }
    $positions[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen(" ");
    $flag++;
}
$new = explode('@',$string);
print_r($new);
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression for that.

```
$founds = array();
$text='Apple Green Yellow Four Seven Gray';
preg_match('/^([^ ]+ +[^ ]+) +(.*)$/', $text, $founds);
```

Refer to the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840863/1061944) too

Comment: My output is `Array ( [0] => Apple Green Yellow Four Seven Gray [1] => Apple Green [2] => Yellow Four Seven Gray ) ` it missed the `Seven Gray` on explode

Comment: view the link I referenced in the answer. It will help you

Answer (score 1):

With the `explode` you can not get desired output. You have to use `preg_match_all` to find all values.
Here is an example :

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z0-9\.]+(?: [A-Za-z0-9\.]+)?)/',
       'Apple Green Yellow Four Seven Gray',$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the type of task for `preg_split()`.

Match every two sets of non-whitespace characters followed by a space.  Use `\K` to reset the fullstring match just before the second space -- this will ensure that every second space will be consumed while splitting.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KcFTB))

```
$string = 'Apple Green Yellow Four Seven Gray';

var_export(
    preg_split('/(?:\S*\K ){2}/', $string)
);
```